# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

```
string query = "UPDATE Completed_orders SET service=N'" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "',kolvo=N'" + kol.Text + "',note=N'" + not.Text + "' WHERE orders='" + form3.ordersgrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dataBase.getConnection());

dataBase.openConnection();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataBase.closeConnection();

form3.serviceklient();
MessageBox.Show("Изменена");
this.Hide();
```

[image]

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__1A00DC411E67C062'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Completed_orders'. The duplicate key value is (23, 1).
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Values of a PrimaryKey must be unique, you have repeated these values.,

Comment: Two PK are FK and when I write in the request for update,and select in where id_orders which is taken from the table orders id

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: `SET service=` clearly you already have that combination in the table. By the way, apart from the major SQL injection issue, you also need to dispose the connection and command objects with `using`. Do *not* cache the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add an occurence in a table when a record with the same id (primary key) already exist.

If it's possible for your project, I suggest you tu use a numeric ID with the autoincrement option :

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` ( id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, [...] );
```

Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table.
When you insert a new record in the table, you don't have to specify the id.

Comment: What if I can't do this in my project?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA6rD.png